# Rails 3: Error with Devise Gem + :uniqueness validaiton

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm running rails 3.2.5 with the latest Devise gem.  And i have a user class that is related to an Actor class.  There is a field called slug that validates fine if I use the following syntax...

```
validates :slug, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }
```

But if I place the extra uniqueness argument

```
validates :slug, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }, :uniqueness => true
```

it throws an error...

```
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#update

undefined method `text?' for nil:NilClass
```

**I'm not sure what is causing such.**

I should also mention that in my user model class I have the following...

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :language, :remember_me, :profile_attributes, :admin, :slug
```

And that in my config file I have

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false #not standard nor recommended I know
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to get around it by separating out validates_uniqueness_of by itself.  So for me

```
validates :username, :presence, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

throws the same error (undefined method 'text?').  while changing to

```
validates_presence_of :username
validates_uniqueness_of :username, { case_sensitive: false }
```

works just fine.